# Particle in a classically allowed region vs forbidden region

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

So what would the momentum be in either of these regions? In terms of the infinite square well where the potential, $V(x) = 0\leq x\leq a$ and infinity otherwise. In the otherwise case, the potential is infinity, so would the momentum be $\it{0}$. In the case where we are in the square well and the potential is $0$, the momentum would be greatest here, but can this be generalized further, or is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure, what are you asking for but considering this:

> So what would the momentum be in either of these regions?

The energy eigenfunction in position basis is given by
$$\phi_n(x)\propto \sin(k_nx)$$
where $k_n=n\pi /L$. Then we know that the momentum eigenfunction has a form
$$\chi(x)\propto e^{ipx/\hbar}$$
Thus  I can write
$$\phi_n(x)\propto (e^{ik_nx}-e^{-ik_nx})$$
so the momentum eigenvalue will be $\hbar k_n$ which says that one of them going to the right and the other on the left which is pretty much reasonable (compare with classical case). The particle is in a superposition of both of them.